# Resolving "No instance for ..." with conduit's mono-traversable

Tags: haskell, conduit

Given the following code:

```
import           Data.Attoparsec.Text
import qualified Conduit as C
import qualified Data.Conduit.Combinators as CC

f :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ()
f infile outfile =
  runResourceT $
    CC.sourceFile infile $$ C.encodeUtf8C =$= x
```

where `x`'s type is `ConduitM Text Void (ResourceT IO) ()`

The following compile-time error occurs in my private github repo:

```
• No instance for (mono-traversable-1.0.2:Data.Sequences.Utf8
                     ByteString Text)
    arising from a use of ‘C.encodeUtf8C’
• In the first argument of ‘(=$=)’, namely ‘C.encodeUtf8C’
  In the second argument of ‘($$)’, namely ‘C.encodeUtf8C =$= x’
  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
    ‘CC.sourceFile infile $$ C.encodeUtf8C =$= x’
```

How can I resolve this compile-time error?

**EDIT**

My understanding of the types:

```
> :t sourceFile
sourceFile
  :: MonadResource m =>
     FilePath
     -> ConduitM
          i bytestring-0.10.8.1:Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString m ()

> :t ($$)
($$) :: Monad m => Source m a -> Sink a m b -> m b

> :t Conduit
type Conduit i (m :: * -> *) o = ConduitM i o m ()

> :i Source
type Source (m :: * -> *) o = ConduitM () o m ()

> :i Sink
type Sink i = ConduitM i Data.Void.Void :: (* -> *) -> * -> *

> :t (=$=)
(=$=)
  :: Monad m => Conduit a m b -> ConduitM b c m r -> ConduitM a c m r
```

`C.encodeUtf8C =$= x` boils down to, I think:

```
(mono-traversable-1.0.2:Data.Sequences.Utf8 text binary,
      Monad m) =>
     Conduit text m binary () 

=$= 

ConduitM Text Void binary ()
```

yielding a return type of

`ConduitM text Void (ResourceT IO) ()`

And I suppose that this type, i.e. `C.encodeUtf8C =$= x`, does not unify to the expected second argument of `CC.sourceFile`?

Comment: There's an instance `Utf8 Text ByteString`. Is something flipped around here? Do you actually need `decode` instead? I'm not super familiar with conduit, but what direction does your last line flow (right to left or left to right)?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz - hi. I updated my question with my understanding of the types. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please post the output of `ghc-pkg list bytestring` and `ghc-pkg list mono-traversable`. Also, what version of ghc are you using? Newer one should produce better error message in such cases.

Comment: @Yuras - `$ghc-pkg list bytestring
/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/8.0.1_4/lib/ghc-8.0.1.20161213/package.conf.d
    bytestring-0.10.8.1
$ghc-pkg list mono-traversable
/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/8.0.1_4/lib/ghc-8.0.1.20161213/package.conf.d`. How do I tell which `GHC` I'm using on this `stack` project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sourceFile` conduit produces a `ByteString`, that you need to **decode** into a `Text` for `x` to consume. **Encoding** refers to the opposite direction where you serialize `Text` to `ByteString` to be written to file.

Use [`decodeUtf8`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-combinators-1.1.1/docs/Data-Conduit-Combinators.html#v:decodeUtf8).

---

### Why the types don't match

```
-- Ignoring the `Monad` constraint.

(=$=)      :: Conduit a m b -> ConduitM b c m r -> ConduitM a c m r

encodeUtf8 :: Utf8 text binary
           => Conduit text m binary

x          :: ConduitM Text Void m ()
```

To apply `(=$=)` to `encodeUtf8`, you must unify `Conduit a m b` and `Conduit text m binary`, so we get the following type equalities:

```
a ~ text
b ~ binary
```

Then we apply the result to `x`, unifying `ConduitM b c m r` and `ConduitM Text Void m ()`:

```
b ~ Text
c ~ Void
```

Up to here the compiler doesn't complain, but we can already see a mismatch because of the two equalities involving `b`:

```
b ~ binary
b ~ Text
```

In the `conduit-combinators` library, the type variable `binary` is used to refer to types that represent raw binary data, typically `ByteString`, as opposed to more structured data like `Text`.

If we continue, the result has type `ConduitM a c m r`, and that is being passed as the second argument of `($$)`.

```
-- Expanding Source and Sink definitions, renaming type variables.

($$) :: Monad m => ConduitM () d m () -> ConduitM d Void m e -> m e

sourceFile infile
     :: _ => ConduitM i ByteString m ()
```

Using `source infile` as the first argument, we unify `ConduitM () d m ()` with `ConduitM i ByteString m ()`.

```
i ~ ()
d ~ ByteString
```

And with our previous `encodeUtf8C =$= x` as the second argument of `($$)`, we unify `ConduitM d Void m e` with `ConduitM a c m r`.

```
a ~ d
c ~ Void
r ~ e
```

Focus on `a` and `d`, we have the following:

```
a ~ text
a ~ d
d ~ ByteString
```

Therefore `text ~ ByteString`, `binary ~ Text`. Now remember that to use `encodeUtf8`, we require a `Utf8 text binary` constraint, i.e., `Utf8 ByteString Text`, which is the wrong way around.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. When you use `~`, e.g. `a ~ text`, can I read that to mean, `a` has type of `text`?

Comment: No, `a` and `type` are both type variables. It means `a = text`, at the type level.